# How to change Rendering method of 360 video

Tags: google-cardboard, google-vr

My problem is that Left monitor and Right monitor display very different scenes(like phicture)
[image]

Now I use VrVideoView for my 360 video player.

```
<com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.VrVideoView
            android:id="@+id/video_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="@null"
            android:layout_height="250dip"/>
```

full code : 
[enter link description here](http://%20http://trimensions.org/node/83)

I just change file name "congo.mp4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this snippet in your code:

If you are using HLS:

```
options.inputFormat = Options.FORMAT_HLS;
```

Otherwise:

```
options.inputFormat = Options.FORMAT_DEFAULT;
```

And If you want to use mono video:

```
options.inputType = Options.TYPE_MONO;
```

Otherwise:

```
options.inputType = Options.TYPE_STEREO_OVER_UNDER;
```

Comment: Did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

options.inputType = Options.TYPE_MONO;